# Bootloader can not be found!

Tags: grub-efi

My computer is a ThinkPad X1 Carbon (Windows 10 by default). I installed Ubuntu 16.10 successfully, and I installed GRUB in the same time. My problem is I can't find the bootloader on my PC. It's been a day I work on that problem but I didn't find a solution. In fact, I install GRUB on `/dev/nvme0n1p5`, but now, what can I do? How could I access my bootloader from my PC?

Answer (score 0):

From working Windows 10, open cmd as administrator and type

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

**Note that in rare situations this command can respond in non working bootloader. So prepare a [bootrepair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) live USB!**

Comment: Could you tell me how to get access the grub rescie terminal?

Comment: The only OS available now is Windows 10.

Comment: I understands that you had no bootloader at all. Edited answer.